# FileLoadException when running C# script with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, csharpscript, dotnet-script

I wrote the following C# script (HelloWorld.csx file):

```
#! "netcoreapp3.1"
#r "nuget: System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, 5.0.0"

public class Script
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

Script.Run();
```

I'm using [dotnet-script](https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script) (version 1.0.1) and [.NET Runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1) (version 3.1.14)

When executing this script, I get the following error. Any idea why?

```
dotnet-script HelloWorld.csx
```

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)
> File name: 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
> ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
> at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath(IntPtr ptrNativeAssemblyLoadContext, String ilPath, String niPath, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)
> at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String assemblyPath)
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFromResolveHandler(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
> at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.InvokeResolveEvent(ResolveEventHandler eventHandler, RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name)
> at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.OnAssemblyResolve(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
> at Submission#0.Script.Run()
> at Submission#0.<>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\HelloWorld.csx:line 18
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Dotnet.Script.Core.ScriptRunner.Execute[TReturn](String dllPath, IEnumerable`1 commandLineArgs) in /private/var/folders/6j/4hkjjhd50fg27s933nctz0480000gn/T/tmp3iI6tV/Dotnet.Script.Core/ScriptRunner.cs:line 52

Comment: Just tried replicating this but it worked for me. I installed dotnet-script as a global tool, created a csx file as shown above and then executed with `dotnet-script code-pages.csx` - no errors. Not helpful I know, but wonder if it is a permissions issue with wherever dotnet script is caching nuget packages?

Comment: @phil_rawlings Which runtime are you using?
You can know which runtimes are installed by running this command: dotnet --list-runtimes

Comment: 2.1.26, 2.127, 3.0.0-preview8-28405-07, 3.1.13, 3.1.14, 5.0.4 and 5.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an issue on the [dotnet-script repo](https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script/) and I got an answer from the dev. [Refer to the issue for all the details](https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script/issues/613).

The answer I got is that dotnet-script version 1.0.1 preloads version 4.7.1 of System.Text.Encoding.CodePages which means a newer major cannot be resolved.